# How to implement a search history textfield like Chrome browser in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to implement a search history textfield like Chrome browser.

Currently my idea is to subclass the `UITextField` and add a `UITableView` to the textfield's superview when something is typed in the textfield.
The data storage is using Core Data.

The new class has a datasource (`UITableViewDataSource`) and a delegate (`UITableViewDelegate`) properties which will be pointed to the `UITableView`.

In my app I've already used a `UITableView` in my `UIViewController` so I use another separate Object as the delegate controller of my custom textfield.

But I have some difficulties dealing with my textfield's tableview events as this table view is added as a subview of the textfield's superview. Whenever I touch the tableview the receiver is always the view under that table view so the table view populated by my custom textfield class couldn't receive my taps on screen.

Comment: Can you be more specific, are you looking for autocomplete textfield ? If yes, check this https://www.cocoacontrols.com/tags/autocomplete

Comment: Check if this helps you:http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/

Comment: Thanks this is indeed very helpful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ditched my original design and decide to use a `UISearchBar` to replace the `UITextField` and put a customized `UITableView` in the `UIViewController` to show the search keywords.

This way it is much easier to manipulate the `UITableView` although it is a little bit tight coupling with the `UIViewController`.